# Bootstrap Resposive Button Link In A Column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Need to place 5 buttons in a download and finally i came with the following code.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
      <a class="btn btn-danger" href="#">Click Here For Music & Rhyme Section</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
      <a class="btn btn-danger" href="#">Click Here For Music & Rhyme Section</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
      <a class="btn btn-danger" href="#">Click Here For Music & Rhyme Section</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
      <a class="btn btn-danger" href="#">Click Here For Music & Rhyme Section</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
      <a class="btn btn-danger" href="#">Click Here For Music & Rhyme Section</a>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

But the issues here is that the text is collapsed in the button. We want the entire the text to visible in the button.

Comment: it looks well in snippet

Comment: use btn-block class

Comment: @Kenry Sanchez You can find the issuse when you click full page

Comment: @SaurabhMistry When i use btn-block full text is not shown

Answer (score 0):

@rakeshkumar you just need to  add class="col-lg-2" to all your divs. it solves my problem.

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
      <a class="btn btn-danger" href="#">Click Here For Music & Rhyme Section</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
      <a class="btn btn-danger" href="#">Click Here For Music & Rhyme Section</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
      <a class="btn btn-danger" href="#">Click Here For Music & Rhyme Section</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
      <a class="btn btn-danger" href="#">Click Here For Music & Rhyme Section</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
      <a class="btn btn-danger" href="#">Click Here For Music & Rhyme Section</a>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```